# Use moq to ignore a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, mocking, moq

I have a method called GetBESummaries which looks like this:

```
public string GetBESummaries()
{
  CheckPermissions();

  /* rest of the code */
}

public void CheckPermissions()
{
   method1();
   method2();
 }
```

I am writing a unit test method using moq and i want my moq to ignore CheckPermissions so that i can avoid mocking the list of method calls from Check Permissions. I wish to prevent the control frm going inside the CheckPermissions method. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, Moq works by overriding implementation for abstract and virtualized members. You would need to break out your permissions logic into either an abstract class or an interface so that it could be overridden. While you're at it, consider giving it a return type so that you can do something with your permissions validation logic outside of the permissions class. Your main class can then require the permissions object in its constructor. For example,

```
public interface IPermissionsChecker
{
    bool UserHasPermissions( // whatever parameters you need );
}

public class PermissionsChecker : IPermissionsChecker
{
    public override bool UserHasPermissions( // same params as above)
    {
        // logic
    }
}
```

Once you're there, mocking it out is very easy. You just build the mock, write the setup logic for how you want it to behave inside of your tests, and feed it into your consuming class. This has the added bonus of improving your encapsulation: if you want to have different methods of confirming permissions, it's simply a matter of submitting a different one to your constructor or calling method!

```
var myMock = new Mock<IPermissions>();
myMock.Setup( m => m.UseHasPermissions()).Returns(true);

var classUnderTest = new GenericConsumerClass(myMock);
```

Comment: This works well for methods that do not call other multiple methods. Currently my methods in CheckPermissions calls thousands of methods..Hence, It still does not answer what someone must do to invoke a call but not go inside the called method.

Comment: I read a solution that uses Verifiable and Verify for virtual and abstract methods but it does not extend it to methods that are not virtual/ abstract.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand; your mocked method won't call any methods under your concrete method, of course, because it's outside of the logic for that method. Is your intent to test the methods inside of the CheckPermissions() call?

Comment: So right now 

 dasMoqSecurityService.Setup(das => das.CheckPermissionsForBusinessEntitySummaries())

takes the control inside CheckPermissionsForBusinessEntitySummaries() method. which i do not want

Comment: I think you misunderstand a little. You're not taking control inside another object's method, you're providing a separate implementation of the class' interface which only has whatever logic you provide it. You don't have to worry about accidentally calling into the SecurityService's methods because as far as your mock is concerned, those methods do not exist.